# Ubuntu won't boot up after certain boots

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 22.04

I've dual boot Ubunutu 22.04 along with windows 11. But after certain boots or after updating Ubuntu it won't boot up. tried reintalling the OS. Also tried with older versions 18.04 and 20.04 but it's of no use.

Here's what it shows while booting up:

[image]

Comment: Install Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0):

During installation you used the Nouveau drivers instead of the recommended NVidia driver. Try an install with the recommended NVidia driver.

Comment: And because dual-booting with Windows 11 that has Secure Boot as a requirement the OP will have to use `mokutil` to sign the Nvidia drivers.